# thread safe vector of functions, each of which can remove access that vector

Tags: c++, function, vector, thread-safety

lets say I have a class that contains a vector of functions (eg. `std::vector<T(*)(...)>`). That class has methods for adding and removing functions from that vectors, as well as invoking them from first to last.

I want this class to be thread safe, so in each of the methods(add, remove and invoke) I use a semaphore(specifically win32 semaphore object) to lock the access to the vector while method finishes working with it. however id like to be able to remove functions from vector in the same thread(only time this would happen is when a function from a vector modifies the vector using add, remove or invoke methods). Is there a way to accomplish this - to lock the vector from being accessed from the other threads, but be able to be accessed from the same thread?

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::recursive_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex). Showing code might help.

Comment: Do you need the change to be immediately visible to other threads or can you wait until the current "chain" is done executing?

Comment: @Botje if by change you mean adding / removing of the functions, then yes. I'd like to be able to remove and add functions to the chain inside of an invocation, so that it will be applied during that invokatio, meaning if one function in the chain removes some next one. Then the removed one is not invoked

Comment: @Jarod42 That seems to be the behaviour I am looking for. thanks a lot!

Comment: Recursive mutexes can be a code smell.  It might be worth reconsidering how you are managing your data.  Without code I'll have to speculate, but it seems like there should be two different method to access the vector.  One from the "outside" which needs to lock and one from the "inside", which does not.  Sounds like the functions are run from the "inside" and so should not be using the same method as those accessing from the "outside".  Often the outside version just locks then calls the inside version.

Comment: @dohashi I really wanted to achieve this using only one set of add remove methods(for simplicity). That is why I was looking at recursive mutexes. Critical sections in Win32 seem to also fit my needs. The problem in my program is that these vectors are invoked on a separate thread(window pump thread, that calls subscribed functions on whatever events) and i want to be able to use add and remove on main thread without fucking up the vector. I can't just lock it on every operation, that will lead to deadlock if function inside it operates on it. Just need to lock it to single thread at a time